# Connect to LAN while Android device is in debugging mode

Tags: android, lan, android-2.2-froyo

I have HTC wildfire running on Android(FROYO) and i am connecting to PC using USB cable,

My PC is having LAN connection having internet access.

How do i connect HTC wildfire on same network?

Note: I don't have wifi connection available and Android device can not be connected on ad-hoc network also.

Is there any way to overcome with this?

Comment: why don't you have wifi ? That 's the way to go. Are you looking for a way to get a network connection via your usb plug ? (to make things clear)

Comment: You should ask programming question here according to [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions） For network configuration, you can ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Thanks for the responses,                                        Actually i found out a way to do this there is some feature called HTC Wifi hotspot using which u can create wifi connection on your phone and connect you PC to same wifi, Note:if u create connection on pc which will be adhoc network and will not be visible in your phone so create it on your phone and connect pc to it

Comment: Much needed qtn. And here i need to access my LAN based server for debugging on a device. Any helpful info .